# Multivalued dependency example tricky

Tags: database, dependencies, key, relationship, modeling

`Employé3: {noEmp, ability, country}`

I have this little set of attributes and the following restrictions: Each employee may have some abilities in relation with a certain country. For instance, Alfred can cook Italian and Chinese food and can write in french.

My problem here is I cant decide what DM would be the best solution. I tried use 
`noEmp,country ->> aptitude`, but it bogs me. It says that I can have two tuples with same `(noEmp,country)`, but not necessarily same aptitude. OK!, but is it enough?

I thought about using `noEmp->>country,ability`, but it doesn't seems to express the relation between the ability and the country.

Of course, all of these DM's are trivial, because it complains all the attributes, so maybe its a silly question...

Just another question: What about the keys? Can I use the DM to determinate it? At first I thought no, because the key must be single. But in this case, I would be forced to use all attributes as keys, what its a little strange, how could I possibly have a 4FN relation if I can't use the DM's to determinate something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pair `(ability, country)` is *compound attribute*. Let's call it `ethnic_ability` for the lack of better term. Compound attributes are complex domains, which are flattened into multiple columns of primitive datatypes. Examples: `(yyyy_mm_ss_date, hh_mm_daytime)`, `(first_name,last_name)`, `(integer_part_of_real_number,decimal)`. From DM perspective compound attribute can be considered atomic. Therefore, you have a table with two columns `{noEmp, ethnic_ability}`, and there is not much what dependency theory can say about binary predicates.